# How do I display a Word document in a rich-edit control?

Tags: delphi, ms-word, richedit, .doc

I'm building a Delphi app and I want to read a Word document and display it in a rich edit. How can I do that?

Comment: Very big ask. In general you won't achieve this. You could save as RTF but the fidelity will be poor.

Comment: Or intead of use a RichEdit put an `TOleContainer` component in your form and then use the `CreateObjectFromFile` method in this way `OleContainer1.CreateObjectFromFile('your doc file path goes here',false);`

Comment: AFAIK, Word provides an ActiveX control for Outlook.

Comment: Asking for emails is not how we do it here.

Comment: ok i managed to import the .doc using a ole container. but now i get error 87: parameter incorrect every time i try tu use it's functionality. that's odd because i didn't modify anything except from adding that ole container and a file-open menu

Answer (score 1):

```
function OpenWordFile(const FName: string): string;
var wordText: string;
begin
  openWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  openWord.Visible := False;
  openWord.Documents.Open(FName);
  openWord.ActiveDocument.Select;
  wordText:= openWord.Selection.Text;
  openWord.ActiveDocument.Close;
  openWord.Quit;
  openWord := unassigned;
  /////
  Result:= wordText;
end;
```

Comment: This does not *display a Word document in a RichEdit*. It opens a Word document and copies plain text to the clipboard (which is absolutely inappropriate behavior - the clipboard is the property of the user, not an application).

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering a 3rd party control that can accomplish this, RichView allows you to import word documents.

http://www.trichview.com/

I believe it uses word itself to do the importing, so your target machines will have to have it installed to be able to import.